# Constrained auto doesn't work for msvc function parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I have decided to go all out and use C++ 20's concepts in a library I am starting.

I have tested the following code on GCC trunk and it runs just fine, however fails on MSVC 16.5.4 with C++20 enabled. Is this feature not confirmed by the standard, has it not been implemented yet, or is my version out-of-date>

Thanks!

```
#include <concepts>

void myFunc(std::integral auto value)
{
    value += 1;
}

int main()
{
    myFunc(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's legal, and seems to be supported from 16.3. What error message does MSVC give?

Comment: I do not know if MSVC implements this yet, but your version is out of date. 16.8.3 is the newest.

Comment: Although the ink is drying on the C++20 standard, the compiler vendors are scrambling to implement the new features.  Using the C++20 standard right now is *bleeding edge*.  (You may ask, why haven't the vendors been working on this all along.  C++20 has a lot of features, and they may focus on some areas and schedule other areas later on their roadmaps.)

Comment: @Eljay haha sounds about right. Yeah I'm okay with being a bit "risky" and using something that's in development. My library will most likely only actually be used in a year or so's time. Hopefully by then all their ducks are in a row and anything I've used has been ironed out! Hehe

Comment: @Eljay: What do you mean, C++20 is bleeding edge? We're already 87 hours into 2021 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC's compiler, as of 19.28 doesn't support constrained auto.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/hWzPh4).

Note that the compiler version is independent of the MSVC suite version.  The compiler major version indicates an ABI change, and minor an improvement.  The suite version is more tied to marketing-ish releases.

Constrained auto did [make it into the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (not a primary source, but 99.9% reliable).